# RSpectra installation had Non zero exit status

Tags: r, installation, package, runumap

I am trying to install umap however the dependency RSpectra needs to be installed to. Whenever I try to install RSpectra, R shows me a result that installation had Non zero exit status. Does any one knows how can I fix this?

```
18 warnings generated.
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++14 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o RSpectra.so eigs_gen.o eigs_sym.o is_sym.o matops.o register_routines.o svds.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [RSpectra.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RSpectra’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/RSpectra’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/74/_l4zh42s1bb4kbkfvptpx6n40000gn/T/RtmpXSJiBl/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘RSpectra’ had non-zero exit status
```